# Custom Icon for a cluster icon in marker Cluster V3

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

How can I add a custom icon(which is obtained from a servlet) as cluster icon. I m using marker Cluster V3.This is my present code.

```
var clusterOptions = { zoomOnClick: false,styles: [{url: "GetImage?TIPO=GU"}]};

var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, clusterOptions);
```

Any help is appreciated.Thanks in advance.

[Edit]

I finally found out what I was doing wrong.The code which I posted above was giving me a cluster icon which was the same image replicated 4 times.This was because the size of the image was very small.So when I specified the height and width it gave me the correct icon.

```
markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
          maxZoom: zoom,
          gridSize: size,
          styles: [{
height:26,
url: "GetImage?TIPO=GU",
width: 27
}]

        });
```

Comment: Have you looked at the [documentation](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/docs/examples.html)?  The "advanced" example allows you to change the cluster icons.

Comment: @geocodezip Yes I had.But I couldn't make out from it.I m sorry I am very new to google maps api.

Comment: If you have simple icon, check this answer about generating it on client side with svg icons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28178080/getting-google-map-markerclusterer-plus-icons-in-one-color/37302915#37302915