# Getting Google Map MarkerClusterer Plus Icons In One Color

Tags: google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

Can some one please let me know how to set MarkerClusterer plus to show all Clusters in One color? as you can see the MarkerClusterer automatically changes the color of the clusters when they are out on a range but I want get them all in one color?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi the colors are defined by the images which came with the cluster.js file

Your images will range from m1.png to m5.png:

[image: markercluster/images]

Just copy the images and make them all the color which you want

Comment: if your going to down vote explain your reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 57):

I had similar problem. Solution: develop a function with color parameter which generates inline svg icon. It's not so difficult to reverse engineer it with basic shapes:

```
 var getGoogleClusterInlineSvg = function (color) {
        var encoded = window.btoa('<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200"><defs><g id="a" transform="rotate(45)"><path d="M0 47A47 47 0 0 0 47 0L62 0A62 62 0 0 1 0 62Z" fill-opacity="0.7"/><path d="M0 67A67 67 0 0 0 67 0L81 0A81 81 0 0 1 0 81Z" fill-opacity="0.5"/><path d="M0 86A86 86 0 0 0 86 0L100 0A100 100 0 0 1 0 100Z" fill-opacity="0.3"/></g></defs><g fill="' + color + '"><circle r="42"/><use xlink:href="#a"/><g transform="rotate(120)"><use xlink:href="#a"/></g><g transform="rotate(240)"><use xlink:href="#a"/></g></g></svg>');

        return ('data:image/svg+xml;base64,' + encoded);
    };

var cluster_styles = [
        {
            width: 40,
            height: 40,
            url: getGoogleClusterInlineSvg('blue'),
            textColor: 'white',
            textSize: 12
        },
        {
            width: 50,
            height: 50,
            url: getGoogleClusterInlineSvg('violet'),
            textColor: 'white',
            textSize: 14
        },
        {
            width: 60,
            height: 60,
            url: getGoogleClusterInlineSvg('yellow'),
            textColor: 'white',
            textSize: 16
        }
        //up to 5
    ];

//...

 markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, {
            //...
            styles: cluster_styles
        });
```

SVG source:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-100 -100 200 200">
    <defs>
        <g id="a" transform="rotate(45)">
            <path d="M0 47A47 47 0 0 0 47 0L62 0A62 62 0 0 1 0 62Z" fill-opacity="0.7"/>
            <path d="M0 67A67 67 0 0 0 67 0L81 0A81 81 0 0 1 0 81Z" fill-opacity="0.5"/>
            <path d="M0 86A86 86 0 0 0 86 0L100 0A100 100 0 0 1 0 100Z" fill-opacity="0.3"/>
        </g>
    </defs>
    <g fill="#004b7a ">
        <circle r="42"/>
        <g>
            <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(120)">
            <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </g>
        <g transform="rotate(240)">
            <use xlink:href="#a"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! Solved my issue when just discovering why all my cluster icons had vanished.

Comment: This is great, and saved me a lot of work. But the comment of "up to 5" for the styles is not correct, I think. You may need to change how the different cluster size are determined (with markerCluster.setCalculator). But that only makes Tomasz's answer even better!

Comment: Great solution! Thanks!

Comment: Dude, if I found this sooner you'd have save me 3 hours of anger. Thank you so much. You really saved the day today

Comment: Absolutely great!

Comment: But keep in mind use it only for cluster background images, not for markers that use img tag since this does not work in IE

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can add/set the styles in the following manner :

```js
import MarkerClusterer from '@google/markerclustererplus';

let cluster = new MarkerClusterer(
                  map, 
                  markers, 
                  {
                    styles: [
                       MarkerClusterer.withDefaultStyle({
                        width: 50,
                        height: 50,
                        anchorIcon: [0, 0],
                        anchorText: [2, 2],
                        url: '/assets/img/m2.png', // This refers to local
                                                   // path of marker's image 
                        textColor: '#ffffff',
                        textSize: 10,
                      }),
                    ],
                  }
);
```